# Wagtail: foreign key to streamfield value

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I would like to allow a dropdown within wagtail admin to select from values (blocks) contained within another model's streamfield, is that possible? I imagined something like:

```
Feedback(page):
    paper = models.ForeignKey('PaperPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False, help_text="The paper associated with this feedback. Auto assigned.")

    content_panels = [
        InlinePanel('paper__drafts_id', label='Draft')   <--- this doesn't work
    ]
```

where

```
Paper(page):
    drafts = StreamField(
            [
                ('draft_block', blocks.ListBlock(blocks.StructBlock([
                    ('date', blocks.DateTimeBlock(required=True, label='Date draft uploaded')),
                    ('uploaded_by', MemberBlock(required=False, label='Uploaded by',
                                                help_text="Who is uploading this draft.")),
                    ('draft_file', DocumentChooserBlock(required=False, label='Upload file')),

                ]), template='papers/blocks/drafts.html')),
            ],
            blank=True
        )
```

but I'm not sure if this is even possible? Any suggestions would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one downside of `StreamField` - the data is not stored as "true" database objects, but only as JSON text stored against the page, so there's no way to define relations such as `ForeignKey`s pointing to individual items in that data.

If there's only one block type in the stream, as in your example code, then it would be a better fit to define 'draft' as a child object (with an `InlinePanel`) on the Paper model instead; it will then exist as a true database model.

Comment: Thanks @gasman, that's what I've gone with for now and it's working well, just curious if there was some functionality available that I had overlooked. Thanks for the amazing framework!!